# python script to pickle entire environment

Tags: python, pickle

I'm working inside the Python REPL, and I want to save my work periodically. Does anybody have a script to dump all the variables I have defined? I'm looking for something like this:

```
for o in dir():
    f=open(o)
    pickle(o_as_object, f)
```

This seems like something other people have done, so I wanted to ask before re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible in such a general way. Not everything in python can be pickled, so you will have to write your own code which decides what to pickle, what not and how to handle unexpected values which cannot be pickled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [Dill](http://dev.danse.us/trac/pathos/wiki/dill):

> In addition to pickling python objects, dill provides the ability to
>   save the state of an interpreter session in a single command. Hence,
>   it would be feasable to save a interpreter session, close the
>   interpreter, ship the pickled file to another computer, open a new
>   interpreter, unpickle the session and thus continue from the 'saved'
>   state of the original interpreter session.

Note that it's still in alpha, so don't rely on it to store critical data.

Of course, some things can't be restored, such as an open file handle. But you can get quite close.

Comment: recent improvement: dill can now pickle open file handles (see [dill on github](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill)); however, if you want file contents, then pass the contents to StringIO which can also be serialized.

Comment: Neat! Does it restore your position in the file as well as re-opening the file?

Comment: Yes. It copies the file pointer so that you will be at the same position in the file, assuming the nothing weird has happened to the file in the meantime.  It also deals with closed file handles, and stdin/stdout/stderr and temporary files... and failing, tries to build a file handle to devnull... and failing that it throws an UnpicklingError.  Not sure if that's the best fail behavior, but that's what's there now.

Comment: ...well, apparently, since 3.2 pickling some file handles are now more strictly not allowed.  The __get_state__ methods have been set to throw an error for many of the derived file objects in the `io` module.  So, it's back to the drawing board for portions of `io` in 3.2 to the present.  **Insert Sad emoticon here.**

Comment: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/871199
...and also in the most recent versions of 2.6.x and 2.7.x.  One man's "bugfix" is another man's "bug", apparently.

Comment: Update: the issues with file pointers is fixed for python 3.x in `dill` now.