# Saving the stack?

Tags: python, ruby, jvm, stack

I'm just curious, is it possible to dump all the variables and current state of the program to a file, and then restore it on a different computer?!
Let's say that I have a little program in Python or Ruby, given a certain condition, it would dump all the current variables, and current state to a file.
Later, I could load it again, in a different machine, and return to it.
Something like VM snapshot function.
I've seen here a question like this, but Java related, saving the current JVM and running it again in a different JVM. Most of the people told that there was nothing like that, only Terracotta had something, still, not perfect.
Thank you.

To clarify what I am trying to achieve:
Given 2 or more Raspberry Pi's, I'm trying to run my software at Pi nº1, but then, when I need to do something different with it, I need to move the software to Pi nº2 without dataloss, only a minor break time.
And so on, to an unlimited number of machines.

Comment: I imagine someone could go crazy with `pickle` and do something vaguely like this, but it would be horrifically fragile and probably not catch everything. It's a bad idea either way.

Comment: Pickling the entire environment is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232798/python-script-to-pickle-entire-environment

Comment: It's possible using a core-dump and is how Perl does it using [`dump`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dump.html). You'd want to ask on superuser.com how to do it, however, as the Perl `dump` docs say, "...This function is now largely obsolete, mostly because it's very hard to convert a core file into an executable."

Comment: thanks, I'm reading about Dill and pickle :)

Comment: Using a core-dump to avoid the startup time only improves the load time of modules and initialization of variables. It won't improve the run time of the code, because it'll still be relying on the interpreter. Also, any open files, database connections, etc. won't be preserved, so you'll have to save in some sort of idle loop and reopen before continuing.

Comment: @The Tin Man: My point has nothing to do with load times or performance. I want to have a portable system :) Let's say, two Raspberry Pi's running the software (simple stuff, no DBs), whenever I need, given a certain command, the software stops running on Pi 1 and starts running at Pi 2. It's just a theory by now, testing and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seams that I was trying to re-invent the wheel.
Check this links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing#DMTCP

http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/10/17/cryopid-freeze-and-unfreeze-processes-in-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

In Smalltalk, yes.

Actually, in Smalltalk, dumping the whole program and restarting is the *only* way to store and share programs. There are no source files and there is no way of starting a program from square zero. So in Smalltalk you would get your feature for free.

The Smalltalk VM offers a hook where each object can register to restore its externals resources after a restart, like reopening files and internet connections. But also, for example integer arrays are registered to that hook to change the endianness of their values on case the dump has been moved to a machine with different endianness.

This might give a hunch at how difficult (or not) it might turn our to achieve this in a language which does not support resumable dumps by design.

All other languages are, alas, much less live. Except for some Lisp implementation, I would not know of any language which supports resuming from a memory dump.

Which is a missed opportunity.

Comment: Hi akuhn, I've been reading Smalltalk By Example, thanks for the tip, but I don't believe Smalltalk is for me :)
I'll give a shot anyway. Thanks

Comment: +1 for mentioning Smalltalk. It's such a pity that its heritage in this matter hasn't been embraced by its so-called descendants used in the contemporary industry. So many possibilities, so much wasted potential.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Mariano demonstrate that using Fuel (object serialization) in Pharo Smalltalk on a recent Esug conference. You could continue debugging and running as long as you don't hit objects not serialized. [Squeak smalltalk](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=9046) runs on the Pi, and if saving an image is good enough for you, this is trivial. We're still waiting for the faster JITting VM for ARM though (part of the Google Summer of Code programme)